# Remove range of columns in numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have an array :

```
e = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3, 4, 7, 4],
              [ 4,  5,  6,  7, 2, 3, 1],
              [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 3, 5, 7]])
```

I want to remove the range of columns from column 1 to column 3, so it should return:

```
e = np.array([[ 0,  4, 7, 4],
              [ 4,  2, 3, 1],
              [ 8,  3, 5, 7]])
```

I've seen some solution , but they remove specific column by its index, not in range, how to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Solved it using :

```
np.delete(e,np.s_[1:3],axis=1)
```

It will delete column in range 1 until 3.

Comment: woow. amazing!!

Comment: Essentially exactly what I wrote. Awesome. \s

Comment: No, @seanmus ... essentially not what you wrote. This is about deleting a **range** of columns (from 1 to 3), not deleting specifically columns 1 and 3. The missing `np.s_` in your answer is the most important part of it all. An answer with just "use `np.s_`" would have been more helpful than "use `np.delete`" (like your answer)

Answer (score 7):

```
e = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3, 4, 7, 4],

              [ 4,  5,  6,  7, 2, 3, 1],

              [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 3, 5, 7]])

np.delete(e, [1,3], axis=1)

>>>array([[ 0,  2,  4,  7,  4],
       [ 4,  6,  2,  3,  1],
       [ 8, 10,  3,  5,  7]])
```

Comment: Solved it using :

np.delete(e,np.s_[1:3],axis=1)
It will delete column in range 1 until 3.